# MapKit auto layout constraints issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I added a new MKMapView onto the ViewController, and set the constraints to 0 using the "Add New Constraints" button. Now, the map view has constraints to the safe area on all four sides with value 0, but there are a few issues:

1. the compiler is throwing a warning saying "Height is ambiguous", even though all four sides are constrained to 0 to the safe area.
2. After I set the constraints, when I switch "View as:" to another device, the mapView doesn't change size in accordance with the constraints (0 to safe area, aka full screen)
3. On iPhone X, with the constraints set, there are white patches on the top and bottom of the screen, when what I want is to have the mapKit take the entire screen (pic below). How can I do this?

[image: constraints set to safe area on all 4 sides with 0]

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same bugginess in the interface builder as you describe in question 1 and 2 from time to time, and I can easily reproduce it now by adding a map view to an empty view, adding top/bottom/leading/trailing-to safe view constraints and switching the view modes around (different devices, landscape portrait).

The only solution I know of is to move the view manually back to where it is supposed to be. The constraint warnings will then disappear.

The issue in your last question is easy to fix though. Select your parent view and uncheck *Safe Area Layout Guide* on the right hand tool area.

[image: Interface builder safe area]

You have to redo your constraints after this, as the safe area you constrained to before is no longer there.

Here are the results with this option checked and unchecked:

[image]

Comment: isn't the legal Apple copyright and legal link position a problem ?

Comment: What are you talking about, @Cublax?

Comment: The legal button down the map, it's opening the legal conditions of use from the map. using Autolayout I can't both have the map on whole the screen + not cover it. But I did it programatically now, otherwise will be a problem to submit the app